# How can I copy photo caption in Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

How can I copy photo caption in Whatsapp?

I tried to copy photo caption but it not able to select text.

Answer (score 5):

> Yes you can, but not forwarding but using sharing option.
>
> If you received a message with captions OR you sent an image with caption and you want to share/forward the same message with multiple contacts, then
>
> **Select the image with caption -> Press Share (instead of forward) -> Choose Contacts**
>
> Voila! You can now share image with captions :)

Source : [How can I forward an image with captions in WhatsApp?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-forward-an-image-with-captions-in-WhatsApp/answer/Vishnu-M-Aiea)

**UPDATE**

Follow these steps for sharing a media with captions.

1. Select the media with caption
2. Click on vertical triple dot icon on top right corner
3. It will open a menu and it will have a share menu item
4. Clicking on share menu item will show the list of apps
5. Select WhatsApp and then choose the contact to whom the media is to be set with caption (refer below given screenshot).

[image: IMG:]

Comment: +1 WhatsApp should make it work like this for both share and forward...

Comment: I do not see the Share option at all. Is it because of Android 6?

Comment: @sureshvv I have added the steps in update section, please check. I am using Android 5.1. WhatsApp has v2.21.3.8

Answer (score 1):

[Universal Copy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.camel.corp.universalcopy) does that

> Copy text from any application: Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, Youtube, Tumblr, News Republic...

(also works with WhatsApp)

If you are on Marshmallow , make sure you give the app Priority notification access so that it shows  in your notification bar and can be activated by tapping app icon